# Sql Server logging tool

Tags: sql-server, logging

I'm creating a web application.

I would like to know if there is a log system for SQL Server.

Otherwise, I think I'll need to create my own table set and make all the query to insert in theses table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to track (audit) what tables are being queried (SELECT), SQL Profiler is about the only way to go.

If you are looking to audit (track) *changes* made to the database (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and even most CREATE, ALTER, and DROPs), you may want to look at triggers and audit tables. There may be third-party tools out there that do this, SQL 2008 has a feature that can also do this for you (I haven't used it, don't yet need it, and can't quickly find it in BOL, but I know it's there), or you can just implement your own--do some searches for "audit tables" and triggers and you'll find loads of examples out there.

...hah, found it! Look for "Change Data Capture", available only in SQL 2008 Enterprise edition.

Comment: Hooo this is Exacly what I need :) Thanks @Philip.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at SQL Server Profiler.  It allows you to start a trace and log all queries to a file, a table or a client.  It comes with the SQL Server client installation.

Answer (score 1):

[Introducing SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx)

[Using SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx)